# using ARC and not caring about manual memory mgmt anymore

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

When one uses ARC, this means we can **forget** about memory management related tasks right? e.g., like deletion/release of the memory we allocated etc.

Two places I know we may need to interfere is retain cycles, and one should use __weak before Outlet ivars in class definitions (if these outlets are not top objects in object hierarchy of the XIB).

Is there something else I have to consider?

Comment: "we can forget about memory management related tasks" - no, it's just that the syntax changed (it is now uglier).

Comment: *"we can forget about memory management"* - no, ARC does not manage Core Foundation objects, malloc()'ed memory, ... - Do you have concrete questions (after reading the ["Transitioning to ARC Release Notes"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)), otherwise I tend to vote as "too broad" or "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: @MartinR A quote for you!!

Comment: @Martin R: I am aware about Foundation objects ... and that ARC does not manage that ...

Comment: @user2054339: Fine, but that is not obvious from your question.

Comment: ok, I guess I should have a look later at doc you referenced to: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html -- it is necessary to look at it right?

Comment: @user2054339: Are you really asking if it is necessary to look at the ARC documentation in order to understand ARC?

Comment: @Martin R: Well sort of, I read a book and thought I had sufficient idea about ARC and what should I do and not do w.r.t to it. but I'll look at the link anyway

Comment: In my experience, some iOS books provide bad or outdated advice. I'd suggest to look at Apple documentation as the authoritative source of information regarding Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Things have changed. 
You should still stick to some pattern related to memory managment / ARC. You won't retain, release, autorelease and dealloc any more.

New:
You would still overwrite a dealloc method and nil all strong references. That is not really required but can be done. But you would not call [super dealloc] any more.

You will declare properties as strong or weak depending on whether you take ownership or not.

If you want to get rid of an object in a way that the memory is freed up, then you have to nil all strong references to that very object. Each strong reference corresponds to one retain. But you cannot call retain on those objects.

You cannot call undeclared methods any more (Without ARC this will generate a compiler warning, with ARC it is an error.) 
You get warnings when using variable selectos (That is using variables of SEL type and perform those on objects) and you should never do that with methods that might have an implact on the retain count (such as alloc).

And you still have plenty of chances of making errors when you interface with areas of the framework that do not ARC, such as core functions.

So it is far away from "forget about" but applying the ARC patterns is less work and less error prone than the former MRC patterns.

Comment: *"You would still overwrite a dealloc method and nil all strong references"* - Why?

Comment: @MartinR, I have asked that myself. I don't really see the reaon in it but adopted the habit from ARC tutorials. Probably "just to be save". However, you would still have to deallocate anything that you allocated and that is not under ARC control. (Core Functions etc.)

Comment: One reason you need to use dealloc to remove your observers from KVO or leak and spew to console.

Answer (score -1):

When using ARC you dont have to use dealloc/autorelease. so, YES you can forget deletion release etc.
The only thing to consider is strong reference cycles, like the one you mentioned here.
Another example is when you use delegate objects.

You can also refer [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/)